# Predict end time of a task

Tags: mathematical-statistics, predictive-models

Is it possible and is there an easy to predict the end time of a job based on the previous data.
By easy way I mean by calculation, not using a complicated model.

e.g. sample of job data

```
StartTime;EndTime;Duration
2021-06-26 19h00;;
2021-06-25 19h00;2021-06-25 19h40;40min
2021-06-24 19h00;2021-06-24 19h45;45min
2021-06-23 19h00;2021-06-23 19h35;35min
2021-06-22 19h00;2021-06-22 19h46;46min
...
```

Is it possible to predict end time, for job started 2021-06-26 19h00 based on previous job ?
If I take the averge time duration and I add it to 2021-06-26 19h00 ?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason that computing the average duration is not sufficient?

Comment: there is no reason, was thinking could be other method. If computing average is "common" I will go with that. Thanks